# About bad gyro calibration ...help me

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run " Rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard" , I got an error from sensor : "
Gyro sensor : Bad Gyro Calibration Offset : the gyro average is outside the
standard deviation. the raw gyro rate : 307 ( always about 307-309). Two of my turtlebots got the same problem. How can I solve this problem. Is the problem here my sensor . My turtlebot is from Clearpath . When I ask Clearpath supportter about gyro sensor , they told me that my gyro sensor is the ST Micro LY330ALH and has a range of +- 300 deg/s.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38215/about-bad-gyro-calibration-...help-me/) by [Hoangnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2629/hoangnguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was solved ...I change with the new sensor board, rosrun dashboard is ok without error.

---

Originally posted by [Hoangnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2629/hoangnguyen/) with karma: 16 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0